# http listener in Mule esb

Tags: mule, esb

I have a probleme with the configuration of the http listener for example when i'm trying to test this example : http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Listener+Connector
I can't find the source (see image). I'm working with mule 3.5.0 CE.

1. what is the probleme?
2. How can i get parameters from url. and send this parameters in json format. Any example please. Thank you in advance.

[image: Capture]

Answer (score 0):

Http Listener is a feature of Mule 3.6 and above ...

So if you want to run the application in your existing Anypoint studio, then you need to download Mule 3.6 runtime in your existing Anypoint studio by going to help menu --> install new software --> put the url http://studio.mulesoft.org/r3/studio-runtimes/ in work with box and hit enter

You will get Mule 3.6 runtime to download like the following

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't want to work with EE i'm working with CE. is the http listener supported by CE if not how can i replace it thank you again.

Comment: The HTTP Listener is a CE feature but only ships from 3.6.0 onwards. If you are working with 3.5.0 CE then you need to look at the HTTP Transport documentation ( http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference) and use an HTTP inbound endpoint instead of the listener, you should find it in the Studio palette under HTTP with no problem. HTH.